# Can't catch error: An invalid form control with name is not focusable

Tags: javascript, forms, try-catch, focusable

JS try catch does not handle the form submission error "An invalid form control with the name `'somename'` is not focusable. I have a tabbed page that shares one submit. When the page loads, the hidden, required field causes bad validation when I move from tab to tab. This would be easy to work around if it triggered a try/catch, and I could look for the message and act appropriately. However, the error skips right by the catch and cannot be handled.

```
var isValidForm = form.checkValidity();
if (!isValidForm) {
    debugger;
    let subbtn = document.getElementById('hiddenbtn');
    let test = null;
    try {
        test = subbtn.click();
    }
    catch (ex) {
        console.log(ex);
        //if "An invalid form...not focusable" don't 
        //return but continue. We're ok with this error.
    }
    test;
    return;
}
```

The catch should catch the error. But, instead, it skips right over it. Can anyone tell me how to detect this error in code without the big mess associated with adding and removing several required attributes?

Answer (score 1):

I created a quick test-case for it:
(Click the test button, the error only appears in the dev console in chrome)

```js
function test() {
  let el = document.querySelector('button[type="submit"]');
  el.click();
  console.log("Still running");
}
```

```css
.hidden_input { display: none; }
button[type="submit"] { margin-bottom: 0.5rem; }
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="hidden_input" class="hidden_input" value="" required />
  <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
<button type="button" onclick="test()">TEST</button>
```

This error only occurs on Chrome though, not on Firefox (at least from my testing).

I would guess that Chrome doesn't propagate the error as javascript error but rather just logs it.
(Neither `window.onerror` nor `try {} catch {}` can handle it)

Your script also continues to execute after the `subbtn.click()`, so it shouldn't be a problem :)

If you still want to get rid of the error, you can disable form validation on the form or simply submit the form instead of pressing the submit button:

```
// Disable form validation:
form.noValidate = true;

// Or directly submit the form without using the button:
form.submit();
```

Comment: I am using it to validate the current tabs inputs. there are like 6 tabs with 2-4 fields each. My guess is that I will need to have nothing required until the user gets to the tab by clicking next. then it works slick and wont let the user continue with native error boxes. I have not tested in FF but it would be nice to have chrome handle the error in a try/catch

Answer (score 0):

You have "test = subtn.click()" in the try block, but you call it outside of the block.

Try calling the click function within the try block and you will catch the error as expected.

```
let test = subtn.click();
try {
    test;
} catch (ex) {
    console.log(ex);
    //if "An invalid form...not focusable" dont return but continue. we're ok with this error
}
return;
```

Comment: In this scenario test will be undefined if the error happens and crashes chrome if not. Thanks for the input though. It was worth a try.

Comment: what about `test = subtn; try{ test.click() } `